# How to bold text from foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have table with results (tennis match). And the goal is to bold winner of the match. I have made loop which works perfectly if match has 3 sets but if I have 2 sets it doesn't show result, it shows (bold) only winner, because I have null in that columns (g5,g6) in table. How to display those results with two sets with empty columns?

```
This is my code.

<?php
            global $wpdb;
            $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT challenger,challenged, date_match, CONCAT(g1,':',g2,' ',g3,':',g4,' ',g5,':',g6) AS result1,
                                          g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6
                                          FROM barbara_results
                                          WHERE date_match
                                          BETWEEN '2015-11-21' AND '2015-12-06'
                                          ORDER BY date_match ASC");

            foreach ( $result as $print )   {
                echo '<td>';
                    if (((int) $print->g1 > ((int) $print->g2)) && ((int) $print->g3 > ((int) $print->g4))|| ((int) $print->g5 > ((int) $print->g6))){
                        echo '<strong>'.$print->challenger.'</strong>';
                    }
                else{
                    echo $print->challenger.'</td>';
                }

                echo '<td>';
                if (((int) $print->g2 > ((int) $print->g1)) && ((int) $print->g4 > ((int) $print->g3))|| ((int) $print->g6 > ((int) $print->g5))){
                    echo '<strong>'.$print->challenged.'</strong>';
                }
                else{
                    echo $print->challenged.'</td>';
                }
                echo '<td>' . date('d.m.Y.', strtotime($print->date_match)).'</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $print->result.'</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $print->result1.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: run an `if` statement to check if you want to make a certain line bold, and then apply the boldness with a variable that contains the correct HTML syntax. .

Comment: I'm sorry. I am begginer. Can you show me both answers or explain a little bit more?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have made huge mistake at the beginning. I thought it would be ok to sum those number but I have realized that is so wrong. Because I have one result with same sum and it won't bold anything. I thought that I should make some combinations like: if g1>g2 and g3>g4 bold challenger else bold challenged. If g1>g2 and g5>g6 bold challenger else bold challenged. Can I do that here? Please help me to finished that? And I am sorry again.

Comment: Honestly, at this point, I think it might be better to gather your thoughts a little more, delete this old question, and create a new question with: **1) a full explanation of what you are trying to do**, **2) your current code**, and **3) where you are stuck**. It's difficult to help when requirements begin to diverge from the original question, but clarifying your question from the start might enable someone else to help you!

Comment: I agree. Thank ypu for your help!

Comment: @Barbara I've updated my answer from earlier for this question. Does that help clarify how to check for `NULL` for the `g5` and `g6` values?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the individual columns `g1, g2, ..., g6` to your `SELECT` statement, as shown in the example below, you can then use (and format) those column results individually in your `foreach` loop.

```
// in the query:
$result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6 ...");
```

According to your notes earlier, there are no tie results for `g5` and `g6`. This should mean that any time `g5` and `g6` are `NOT NULL`, we can find a winner just from a simple `if (g5 > g6) ... else ...` type of comparison. If `g5` and `g6` are `NULL`, it should indicate that there are no tie results for the `g1 > g2` and `g3 > g4` comparisons in the last `else` block, which allows us to find a winner there.

The following example shows one way to check if a value is `NULL` by using the [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function.

```
// in the foreach loop:
foreach ($result as $output) {
  // check if g5 and g6 are NOT NULL
  // this allows us to avoid the g1, g2, g3, g4 else statement below
  if (!is_null($output->g5) && !is_null($output->g6)) {
    if ((int) $output->g5 > (int) $output->g6) {
      echo '<strong>' . $output->challenger . '</strong>';
    } else {
      echo '<strong>' . $output->challenged . '</strong>';
    }
  } else {
    if (((int) $output->g1 > (int) $output->g2) &&
        ((int) $output->g3 > (int) $output->g4)) {
      echo '<strong>' . $output->challenger . '</strong>';
    } else {
      echo '<strong>' . $output->challenged . '</strong>';
    }
  }
}
```

***Note:*** The `(int)` parts ensure that you are checking **integer values** from your database `g1, g2, ..., g6` columns.

Comment: I want to display result like this on my site: 7:5 6:7 10:8 (tennis - match result) and I  want to show it in one column. And because of that I have used concat. Ok, I'll  try this!

Comment: Great!! I really appreciate that! Thank you!

Comment: No,it won't show results without third set. Can you put it in my code. Maybe I did something wrong with inserting in code?

Comment: I have one huge problem! I have noticed that I have one match where challenger and challenged have same sum - 6:4 2:6 12:10 . OMG! What can I do with that?? The winner is challenger but what to do? Do you have an idea?

Comment: I have huge problem with that result. Because it won't show bold text. Maybe I could put coupe of combinations like if g1, g3 is bigger than g2, g4..and g1 and g5 is bigger that g2, g6 but witout the sum?? I don't know. Is that to complicated?

Comment: I have read your answer but it can't be tie. There have to be winner. Because of that they play third set.

Comment: It's ok! ;) It can't be tie. They play until result is for example 10:8 or 20:18. Do you see my code? It like yours, first one... Link in link that you gave me.

Comment: It's doesn't work. And one thing we don't need any more this: g1 + g3 as challenger_total, g2 + g4 as challenged_total because it is wrong. I have to do something like this : $g1 > $g2 && $g3>$g4 || $g5>$g6... it is working in example that I post you.. In my database 5th and 6th column is null or empty and because of that it doesn't show.. I have to do something like !empty or is not null ... but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT challenger,challenged, date_match, CONCAT(g1,':',g2,' ',g3,':',g4,' ',g5,':',g6) AS result1,
                                      g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6
                                      FROM barbara_results
                                      WHERE date_match
                                      BETWEEN '2015-11-21' AND '2015-12-06'
                                      ORDER BY date_match ASC");

        foreach ( $result as $print )   {

            $sum1 = (int) $print->g1 + (int) $print->g3 + ( is_numeric($print->g5) ? (int) $print->g5 : 0 );
            $sum2 = (int) $print->g2 + (int) $print->g4 + ( is_numeric($print->g6) ? (int) $print->g6 : 0 );
            $challenger = ($sum1 > $sum2) ? '<strong>'.$print->challenger.'</strong>' : $print->challenger;

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $challenger.'</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $print->challenged.'</td>';
            echo '<td>' . date('d.m.Y.', strtotime($print->date_match)).'</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $print->result.'</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $print->result1.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you! I understand now. I have one more question. What if g5 and g6 does not exist? I have one result 6:1 6:1 and it won't show anything because we have $print->g5 and $print->g6 . How make if statement inside that?

Comment: @Barbara I added some logic to check if the variable is a number. If not, then it will add 0.

Comment: In first case it works (before edit). Now I have problem with is_number. Now it shows is_number like undefined function and it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I have put is_numericand it shows like in first case... without result which has 2 sets in tennis vocabulary or just with 6:1 6:1

Comment: Yes, yes i have changed that but it want show that result like in first case. But results with 6:1 1:6 7:6 works great!!

Comment: I re-added the (int), try now.

Comment: Try replacing 'is_numeric' with '!empty'

Comment: $sum1 = (int) $print->g1 + (int) $print->g3 + ( !empty($print->g5) ? (int) $print->g5 : 0 ); something like that? no, it won't work. I also put ? (int) $print->g5 : ' ' );  I really don't know what's wrong... And I  also wrote without if and else statement (? :) but no...

Comment: In my table in database I put that only g5 and g6 can be null. Is it ok?